# How to display selected contacts into next View Controller in IOS 9(Swift)

Tags: ios

In Swift I have displayed contacts from my phone using contact UI framework and  I selected particular contacts .After selecting that  I need  to display that selected contacts in the next View Controller. 
This code belongs to display contacts from contactUI framework. When we run this code it display all the contacts from phone with 2 buttons like done or cancel.When I selects the contact and press the button done it should navigate to another view Controller Plz Provide me a solution for that.

```
enter code here
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Spliting
//
//  Created by Vijayasrivudanti on 01/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Vijayasrivudanti. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController ,CNContactPickerDelegate{
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var results:[CNContact] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func contact(_ sender: Any) {
        //let dataArray = NSMutableArray()
        let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        cnPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        do {
            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactMiddleNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactEmailAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor])) {
                (contact, cursor) -> Void in
                self.results.append(contact)
                ///let data = Data(name: contact.givenName)
                //self.dataArray?.addObject(data)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Handle the error please")
        }

    }
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        contacts.forEach { contact in
            for number in contact.phoneNumbers {

                print("The number of \(contact.givenName) is: \(number.value)")

        }
      }
    }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
        print("Cancel Contact Picker")
    }



}
```

Comment: plz help me if anyone knows the answer

Comment: @ Lahari Areti:  selected contacts  save in array and pass that array to next view controller.

Comment: how to take the selected contacts into array in iOS

Comment: can you give an example plz

Comment: plz check below example and let me know

Answer (score 2):

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView*listTblView;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITableView*listTblView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIButton*selectAll;


-(IBAction)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
-(IBAction)selectAndDeselectAll:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import <Contacts/Contacts.h>
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "TableViewCell.h"
    #import "secondViewController.h"


    @interface ViewController ()
    {
        NSMutableArray *titleArr;
        NSMutableArray  *selectedBtnArray;

    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize listTblView,selectAll;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        titleArr = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self fetchContactsandAuthorization];
        selectedBtnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }



    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
    {
        return titleArr.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
        TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
         }

        cell.title.text = titleArr[indexPath.row];
        cell.selectBitton.tag = indexPath.row ;
         [cell.selectBitton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        for(NSString *name in titleArr)
        {
            if([selectedBtnArray containsObject:name])
            {
               cell.selectBitton.selected = YES;

            }else{
                cell.selectBitton.selected = NO;
            }
        }

    return cell;

    }



    //For fetching contact list from phone call this one

    -(void)fetchContactsandAuthorization
            {
                // Request authorization to Contacts
                CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
                [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (granted == YES)
                    {
                        //keys with fetching properties
                        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
                        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
                        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
                        NSError *error;
                        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
                        if (error)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSString *phone;
                            NSString *fullName;
                            NSString *firstName;
                            NSString *lastName;
                            UIImage *profileImage;
                            NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                                // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                                firstName = contact.givenName;
                                lastName = contact.familyName;
                                if (lastName == nil) {
                                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                                }else if (firstName == nil){
                                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                                }
                                else{
                                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                                }
                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                                if (image != nil) {
                                    profileImage = image;
                                }else{
                                    profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                                }
                                for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                                    phone = [label.value stringValue];
                                    if ([phone length] > 0) {
                                        [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                                    }
                                }
                                NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                                [titleArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"]]];
                                NSLog(@"The contactsArray are - %@",titleArr);
                            }
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [listTblView reloadData];
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }];
            }
```

For select particular item  call this method

```
-(IBAction)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.listTblView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.listTblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    TableViewCell *cell = [self.listTblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *tagString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.title.text];
    NSLog(@"title is : %@",tagString);


    if(!sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = YES;
        [selectedBtnArray addObject:tagString];
    }else{
         sender.selected = NO;
         [selectedBtnArray removeObject:tagString];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",selectedBtnArray);

    if (selectedBtnArray. count == titleArr.count)
        selectAll.selected = YES;
    else
        selectAll.selected = NO;

}
For select all and de select all call this method



     -(IBAction)selectAndDeselectAll:(id)sender
        {
            if(!selectAll.selected)
            {
             [selectedBtnArray removeAllObjects];
                selectAll.selected = YES;

                for(NSString *name in titleArr)
                [selectedBtnArray addObject:name];

            }else{
                selectAll.selected = NO;
                 [selectedBtnArray removeAllObjects];
            }

             NSLog(@"%@",selectedBtnArray);
            [listTblView reloadData];
        }
```

saved the selected one in user defaults in

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedBtnArray forKey:@"test"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

In NextViewController , retrieve the  user defaults  in viewDidLoad

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"test"];
     NSLog(@"comtactList :>>>>%@",arr);
```

Comment: is it in swift or objective-c?

Comment: This is in objective-c

Comment: Plz can you provide me it in Swift.

Comment: ok.Give me some time  i will give u or you can convert objective c code to swift using this link  https://objectivec2swift.com/. It will convert objc to swift and it may be helpful.

Comment: ok sure you can post, But what is your problem explain clearly

Comment: By using  contacts UI framework I displayed all the contacts from my phone and I selected Particular contact.That selected contacts should be displayed in the next view controller. My problem is we are selecting the contacts from default UI and  I don't know how to navigate it to other page.

Comment: This example is shows like that only but it is objective c.if u want swift i wll give

Comment: I want in swift

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your receiving viewController, initialise another results array:

```
var receivingResults:[CNContact] = []
```

In the first viewController: send the results array to the receiving viewController's receivingResults array in prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "REPLACEWITHSEGUEIDENTIFIER" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? REPLACEWITHNAMEOFDESTINATIONVIEWCONTROLLER {
                destination.receivingResults = self.results

            }
        }
}
```

And where you fetch the results in `@IBAction func contact(_ sender: Any)`, you can save to results the array of CNContacts...

```
self.results = contact
```

OR

```
for cont in contact {
    self.results.append(cont)
}
```

Then do with the receivingResults array how you want...

Comment: I got the error at self.results. like Cannot assign value of type '[CNContact]' to type 'CNContact.

Comment: I see @LahariAreti your `self.results.append(contact)` should be `self.results = contact`.

Comment: it doesn't go to another view controller. I got the error like the  'Result View Controller  is unreachable because it doesn't have no entry points and no identifier for runtime'. how we connect from default contact view controller ui to result view controller. whenever user select the contact and press done button in  default ContactView Controller it goes to Result View Controller with selected Contacts. How we put link between done and Result View Controller?

Comment: Hello @Louis Leung

Comment: hi @LahariAreti Do you know how to connect segues in storyboard? (See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) You need to connect between the done button to the ResultViewController, and then set the segue identifier and use that string in the prepareForSegue() where I put REPLACEWITHSEGUEIDENTIFIER.  A "show" segue should be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: The done button is placed at default controller. I am in dilemma how we will connect to result view controller.please clarify to me. I removed the func contact picker it doesn't show the Done button . so how we put action to done button.

Comment: I took two view controllers.In first view controller I placed a button whenever user clicks a button it display a contact details and user selected the contacts and he click done button it goes to another view controller . so I put second view controller to display selected contacts from default contact view controller not from the first one.so I stuck at how to link done button with second view controller.

Comment: hi @LahariAreti,  I think "performing segues" already has multiple answers on SO that you can look up.  Otherwise, it would be best to start a new question and post the code for both viewController ("default" and "results") together with a screenshot of the storyboard, because I don't think I can see the source of your problem from the code you posted.